# Unable to run the following Python code

Tags: python

This program is basically a script to scan each host in a subnet by actually pinging each ip.
This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os 
global lis 
print("Scanning the Subnet : ")
subnet_input = '192.168.1.0'
subnet_input = subnet_input.split('.')
for x in range(0,255):
    subnet_input[3] = x
    str(subnet_input)
    new_sub = str(subnet_input[0])+'.'+str(subnet_input[1])+'.'+str(subnet_input[2])+'.'+str(subnet_input[3])
    res = os.system("ping -c 4 {}".format(new_sub))
    if res==0:
        print("{} is Alive".format(new_sub))
        str(new_sub)
        lis = lis + " " + new_sub
    else:
        continue
print("[*] ALL ALIVE HOSTS ARE  : ")
for i in lis:
    print(i)
```

Error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./Ping.py", line 16, in <module>
lis = lis + " " + new_sub
NameError: global name 'lis' is not defined
```

Even though i have declared a global variable it gives me an error saying that the variable is not defined

Comment: What variable is it saying is not defined?

Comment: There is no function here. Everything is in global scope, so declaring global doesnt make sense. What is the error?

Comment: global variable lis

Comment: wait i'll add the error in code

Comment: `lis` is supposed to be a string? If so, swap `global lis` for `lis = ''`

Comment: replace `global lis` with `lis = ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) statement works.

When you declare a variable global, you tell python that it should be accessible everywhere. However, you still need to give it a value.

In your code, you do:

`global lis`

But you never assign `lis` a value. Therefore, when you attempt to access it here:

```
lis = lis + " " + new_sub
```

You of course get a NameError. `lis` does not have a value for you to access.

To fix this, replace `global lis` with `lis = ""`. Doing `global lis` *and then* assigning a value to it will also work. However, since everything seems to be in the global namespace in your example, this is unnecessary.

Comment: But i have another doubt : when i run the scan there are two potential ip 
ie: 192.168.1.101 and 192.168.1.104 
but this ip don't add up in the list named "lis"

Comment: Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) since it solved your issue, and best of luck.

Comment: You statement on global may need a little more info. The fact that the user is placing global in the global name space will not work if they try to reference a global variable within a function. You should clarify that the global statement needs to be in the function that needs to call said global variable.

Comment: That is a completely separate issue. Thus, you should post it as a separate question, and get help from someone more knowledgeable regarding this.

Comment: yea sure but i need to wait for 5 minutes to mark as helped !

Comment: @user6369925 btw `lis` is not a list. It is a string.